YA novel with a front cover featuring a haunted house and a blonde (?) girl’s eye in the top-right
I read this book 15 years ago, and cannot remember what it was called. I only remember really liking it.
It was a young-adult novel with a front cover featuring a haunted house and a blonde (?) girl’s eye in the top-right.
Is anyone familiar with the cover or what this book might be?

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! There's not a lot to go on here, could you have a look at these tips for asking story-id questions and [edit] in anything that comes to mind? Was the girl the main character? Who owned the house? Was it part of a series? Can you recall any info about the author maybe? No detail is too small
